# J: How to efficiently apply a verb to prefixes of suffixes?

Tags: list, prefix, j

I have a list

```
   n =: i.3
```

and I want to have an adverb **a** such that **u a n** applies **u** to *prefixes of suffixes* of **n**:

```
   <a n
┌─────────────┬───────┬───┐
│┌─┬───┬─────┐│┌─┬───┐│┌─┐│
││0│0 1│0 1 2│││1│1 2│││2││
│└─┴───┴─────┘│└─┴───┘│└─┘│
└─────────────┴───────┴───┘
```

I've written a sentence that produces desirable result for verb **<**:

```
   ([: <@]\&.> <@]\.) n
┌─────────────┬───────┬───┐
│┌─┬───┬─────┐│┌─┬───┐│┌─┐│
││0│0 1│0 1 2│││1│1 2│││2││
│└─┴───┴─────┘│└─┴───┘│└─┘│
└─────────────┴───────┴───┘
```

but I cannot get how to make an adverb to use it with any verb.

I see another approach to this problem:

```
   a =: \\.
   <a n
┌─┬───┬─────┐
│0│0 1│0 1 2│
├─┼───┼─────┤
│1│1 2│     │
├─┼───┼─────┤
│2│   │     │
└─┴───┴─────┘
   ([: < (a: ~: ]) # ])"1(<a n)
┌─────────────┬───────┬───┐
│┌─┬───┬─────┐│┌─┬───┐│┌─┐│
││0│0 1│0 1 2│││1│1 2│││2││
│└─┴───┴─────┘│└─┴───┘│└─┘│
└─────────────┴───────┴───┘
```

but it is also written specifically for **<**, and maybe not efficient. And I still cannot get how to make an adverb.

It will be even better if I can get the following result:

```
   <a n
┌─┬───┬─────┬─┬───┬─┐
│0│0 1│0 1 2│1│1 2│2│
└─┴───┴─────┴─┴───┴─┘
```

For example:

```
   (10&#.)a n
0 1 12 1 12 2
```

Help me please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is (almost) already an adverb for this. It's the [Spread (`S:`)](http://www.jsoftware.com/docs/help701/dictionary/dscapco.htm) which you want to apply to level `0`.

E.g.

```
<\ each <\. n
┌─────────────┬───────┬───┐
│┌─┬───┬─────┐│┌─┬───┐│┌─┐│
││0│0 1│0 1 2│││1│1 2│││2││
│└─┴───┴─────┘│└─┴───┘│└─┘│
└─────────────┴───────┴───┘
< S:0 <\ each <\. n
┌─┬───┬─────┬─┬───┬─┐
│0│0 1│0 1 2│1│1 2│2│
└─┴───┴─────┴─┴───┴─┘

+/ S:0 <\ each <\. n
0 1 3 1 3 2

(10&#.)  S:0 <\ each <\. n
0 1 12 1 12 2
```

In other words, your `a` could be like this:

```
a =: 1 :'u S: 0 ([: <\&.><\.) y'
```

*(edit)* or, as @Tikkanz says in the comments below, you can avoid `S:` and use the more efficient:

```
a=: 1 : ';@([: u\&.> <@]\.)'
```

or

```
a=: 1 : ';@(<@(u\)\.)'
```

Comment: Thank you, Eelvex. I haven't knew S: primitive.

Comment: alternative without using `S:` is: `a=: 1 : ';@([: u\&.> <@]\.)'`

Comment: or simpler `a=: 1 : ';@(<@(u\)\.)'`

Comment: Thank you, @Tikkanz! It is more efficient: `%/ (6!:2 ,. 7!:2) '(10&#.) S:0 ([:<\&.><\.) i.100' ,: ';@(<@((10&#.)\)\.) i.100'` gives `1.55052 170.946`